# Store numpy array with its corresponiding keys

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 100 000 numpy arrays of shape (300,40,1) and I have a key associated to each numpy array.

What is the best way to store this numpy array with its corresponding key for fastest writing and loading?

Should I use numpy, pandas, pickle, shelve, a dictionary?

Since it is already a numpy array, maybe The best would be to add the key to each numpy array?

I don't mind using pandas as well, since its faster writing and loading than numpy, I just don't know how ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at hdf5 and its associated python library https://www.h5py.org/

Comment: Use [`numpy.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html). Alternatively, use a structured array and [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) that.

Comment: I tried with a dictionary but when I try to store it with dict.dump does not accept numpy arrays, when I tried with pickle.dump it takes a lot of memory, when I tried with shelve it takes a lot of time

Comment: You can create array of shape (100000, 300,40,1) and `dict` with key to index association and store it in different files. Also look at [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

Comment: @mitevva_t you could also try to store it in a MongoDB, using the keys to identify each list